# Facebook page tab app is not visible for a person authorized as an page owner

Tags: tabs, admin, facebook-page, owner

I have FB page with a tab where an application is located.
The visitors are seeing it properly. 
And I can see it to, but just before I authorized as a page owner. Right after that I see an empty tab with no iframe loaded. I checked a page code, a there is no iframe at all.

How to do it visible? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.